# kartik Select2 FilterType in gridview doesn't work

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2, kartik-v

I have an issue about kartik select2 filterType that doesn't work , this is a portion of my code :

```
[
                    'format' => ['link',$idmodel],
                    'attribute' =>$attribute,
                    'filterType'=>GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
                    'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                    'data' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($model_::find()->all(),$attribute,'nom_'.strtolower($idmodel)),
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => '-'.$idmodel.'-'],
                    'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
                    'theme' => Select2::THEME_KRAJEE,

                    ],
```

When i comment this line :

```
'filterType'=>GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
```

a text field appear in my filter grid view.
Can any one help me ??
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's logical that it appears. You want to hide it?

Comment: try to unset js file Assets 

Add this line at end of your file 

unset($this->assetBundles['kartik\widgets\Select2Asset']);

Answer (score 1):

I believe by default `GridView` enables filtering unless you manually disable it. When you comment that out, it uses default text input instead of `Select2`. To also disable that one, use this on columns you want to disable filtering:

```
'filter' => false,
```

Comment: Noo i don't won't to hide it, i want to have this filter , but in my case the select 2 doesn't work.
the other type of filter work like : FILTER_DATE.

Comment: Ok, I see. My mistake. I thought you want to hide it. I'll check tomorrow what are the possible problems.

Comment: No problem
I have added bootstrap.css in my asset and the select2 appear in like a dropdown a not in select2 filter of kartik extension.
Another point , the select2 work fine in _search and _form file

Comment: it seems like a jquery file is missing because, all works fine when i added Jquery.min.js.
Unfortunatly another problem appear when i choose option from my select, it becomes a dropdown

Comment: Also i added this code in the header :
`
$('#id_gridview').ready(function() {

$("select").select2({    
                                           theme : "krajee",
                                           allowClear: true});
});`

Comment: Check network and console. I'm sure there's an error, indicating what's wrong.

Comment: And what about network? Are all included files found?

Answer (score 1):

As I see it from your conversation with Edvin Tenovimas your problem is that no jQuery Javascript file is loaded. Did you installed the Select2 package normally with composer?

```
$ php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2 "@dev"
```

In that case you have to see the file `vendor/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js`. The file has to be copied into your assets directory under `web/assets` automatically. You could remove the content of the assets directories to force the creation of the assets again.

```
$ rm -rf web/assets/*
```

Comment: if i do as you said and add jquery.js to my assets, many other errors appears due to conflicts with jquery because other are loaded.
 $(...).select2 is not a function
jQuery(...).datecontrol is not a function
Also all the select2 doesn't work , the unique solution that i reach it for now is  to remove jquery in my assets config and all works fine except select2 filter in the gridview

Comment: Something is wrong in your composer settings or you installed something manually or you included manually some jQuery Javascript files in your code, what causes conflicts. BTW normally you can find `jquery.js` in your assets and not  `jquery.min.js`. Probably you included both. Check your HTML (CTRL-U in the browser), look for `jquery.js`  and  `jquery.min.js`.